# Добавить Enum поле со значением по умолчанию

Tags: sql, postgresql

postgres: 9.6.3
Скрипт создания таблицы:

```
CREATE TYPE "role_type_enum" AS ENUM('guest', 'user', 'admin', '0', '1', '2')
CREATE TABLE "role" ("id" SERIAL NOT NULL, "type" "role_type_enum" NOT NULL DEFAULT '[0]', "description" character varying NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT "PK_b36bcfe02fc8de3c57a8b2391c2" PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
```

Получаю ошибку:

> QueryFailedError: invalid input value for enum role_type_enum: "[0]"

Как правильно указать "guest" в качестве значения по умолчанию?

Comment: `"type" "role_type_enum" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'guest'`

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно, оформите как ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте именно требуемое значение, а не его порядковый номер в определении типа:

```
CREATE TYPE "role_type_enum" AS ENUM('guest', 'user', 'admin', '0', '1', '2');

CREATE TABLE "role" ( "id" SERIAL NOT NULL, 
                      "type" "role_type_enum" NOT NULL DEFAULT 'guest', 
                      "description" character varying NOT NULL, 
                      CONSTRAINT "PK_b36bcfe02fc8de3c57a8b2391c2" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
                    );
```